# Using RPGLE what hex characters do I use to simulate a keyboard ALT/Enter

Tags: rpgle

I have several comments that need to go into one EXCEL cell and I want them broken out as each comment.  If I'm using EXCEL and I want to perform this, I would use ALT and ENTER.  What HEX characters do I use to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

So if you are using Apache POI to create your spreadsheet, you insert an `x'25'` which is a newline character. I believe that you also have to set the cell to word wrap to make this work. This code is an EBCDIC new line code, Java converts that to an ASCII new line for you.